# Accomodate multiple values using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have regex string `/^(?:\[)(.*)(?:\|)(.*)(?:\|)(.*)(?:\|)(.*)(?:\|)(.*)(?:\])$/` that captures the following value `[john|doe|doe@email.com|doe_avatar|manager]`.
I also like to capture the value with `[john|doe|doe@email.com|doe_avatar]` using the same regex for both. How can I do that in **Javascript**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is doable with a single regex, by enclosing the last segment and its accompanying pipe `\|` in an additional, optional, non-capturing group (`(?:……)?`).

```js
const regex =
    /^(?:\[)(.*?)(?:\|)(.*?)(?:\|)(.*?)(?:\|)(.*?)(?:(?:\|)(.*?))?(?:\])$/

const rows = [
    '[john|doe|doe@email.com|doe_avatar|manager]',
    '[jane|doe|jane@email.com|jane_avatar]',
]

const parse = str => {
    const m = str.match(regex)
    
    if (!m) return null
    
    const [fullMatch, forename, surname, email, avatar, role] = m
    
    return { fullMatch, forename, surname, email, avatar, role }
}

console.log(rows.map(parse))
```

As @CertainPerformance mentions below, the results from the final capturing group will be `undefined` if the match isn't present

Comment: OP says: *I also like to capture the value with `[john|doe|doe@email.com|doe_avatar]` using the same regex for both.* The issue is with the existence or nonexistence of the last one - the `|doe_avatar`, which may or may not exist. Either that last item won't be captured, or it'll be captured, but in the version which lacks the last item, an `undefined` will be put into the resulting group. Either way, a bit of post-processing will be needed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Wow, I really can't read. It's still possible with a single regex, but I was answering completely the wrong question. Editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: It now returns `"role": undefined` when the last part is missing. *Either way, a bit of post-processing will be needed* if OP wants an array of matched sections (and wants to avoid matching elements inside possibly-unbalanced brackets).

Comment: OP didn't mention they wanted an array of matched sections.

Comment: Question should be clarified, but it's what his current code results in: an array where the first item is the full match, and the rest of the array items being each matched section, with no `undefined`s.

Comment: I mean to be fair, `['str']` and `['str', undefined]` _both_ give `undefined` if you try to access them at index `1` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This works for me. I only needed only the first four values from both lists. Thank you @LionelRowe. I cannot upvote because I do not have enough points. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want each section to be in a separate group, it's not possible in a single iteration of a regex pattern in JS (though it's possible in .NET and other flavors where repeated group matches can be extracted). The best you'll be able to manage is matching `[` eventually followed by `]`, and then splitting by `|`s afterwards:

```js
const extract = (str) => {
  const insideBrackets = str.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/)[1];
  const sections = insideBrackets.split('|');
  console.log(sections);
};
extract('[john|doe|doe@email.com|doe_avatar|manager]');
extract('[john|doe|doe@email.com|doe_avatar]');
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible in JS. See my answer